# .htaccess WINDOWS SERVER

Tags: php, windows, .htaccess

Tengo un proyecto PHP con el siguiente .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?PATH_INFO=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Pero ahora quiero montar mi proyecto en un servidor windows Server he leido sobre archivos web.config pero tengo entendido que es para aplicaciones ASP. Me pueden ayudar para que mi htacces funcione en windows Server

Comment: Asumo que estás hablando de IIS?

Comment: Es correcto (Internet information service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el administrador de IIS creas un sitio, luego lo seleccionas y buscas en caracteristicas **URL REWRITE** ingresas y  en el panel derecho seleccionas **Importar Regla** copias en el campo de texto tu codigo htaccess y automáticamente genera la regla para tu sitio, das aplicar y Listo.

Les dejo el Post con la solución.

http://pro7.co/url-rewrite-htaccess-en-windows-server/

Comment: ¿podrías agregar más detalles de la solución?

Comment: Claro ya enseguida la detallo

Comment: Podrías detallarlo el link que compartes no carga